# SharePoint 2010 Claims authentication and custom WCF Service

Tags: sharepoint-server, claims-based-auth, wcf

Can someone help me to give idea on implementing custom WCF service in SharePoint 2010 configured to claims based authentication? 
I have implemented WCF service and deployed to ISAPI folder. When I deploy this to a web application with classic authentication enabled, all looks good. But, with claims based authentication the service is failing.

Can someone please help me? I have read and tried all the internet article already. Used with WsHttpBinding, basicHttpBinding and webHttpBinding. 
I am not using HTTPS, it's on HTTP protocol.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

In terms of getting you started, I would suggest breaking this into manageable items.

> [Getting Started Building a WCF Web Service](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2010/05/11/getting-started-building-a-wcf-web-service.aspx)
>
> Shows how to create a very simple web service using WCF.  Shows how to
>   host this web service using IIS.
>
> [Determining Caller Identity within a WCF Web Service](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericwhite/archive/2010/05/13/determining-caller-identity-within-a-wcf-web-service.aspx)
>
> Enhances the example so that the Web service can authoritatively
>   report on the identity of its caller.
>
> [Establishing Trust between a WCF Web Service and the SharePoint 2010
>   Security Token Service](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2010/06/18/establishing-trust-between-a-wcf-web-service-and-the-sharepoint-2010-security-token-service.aspx)
>
> Configures the example developed in the previous article so that it
>   uses a self-signed certificate to support a secure connection.
>
> [Consuming a Claims-Enabled WCF Web Service as an SharePoint 2010
>   External Content Type](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2010/06/18/consuming-a-claims-enabled-wcf-web-service-as-an-sharepoint-2010-external-content-type.aspx)
>
> Walks through the procedure for consuming a claims-enabled web service
>   as a SharePoint 2010 External Content Type.

Lastly, for your awareness when a web application is configured to use claims authentication (Windows claims, form-based authentication claims, or SAML claims), the Internet Information Services (IIS) website is **always** configured to have anonymous access turned on.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue after spending couple of frustration hours on it.

Finally, I am using the webHttpBinding and it's working fine in Windows Authentication as I have mentioned.

And I am using client as Jquery AJAX. So, along with my request I am also passing RequestDigest and it fixed my issue. Now, all good.

Hope this will help!